# Links Regex Replace HTML with new

Tags: jquery, html, css, regex

I'm trying to run a regex to to do this:

Replace all instances of an apk file in a document:

```
<a href="http://download.mydomain.com/files/androidfile.apk">
```

With:

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://mydomain.com?f=http://download.mydomain.com/files/androidfile.apk">
```

With this JQUERY code:

```
$('body').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3;
}).each(function() {
    $(this).replaceWith($(this).text().replace(/<a href~/^.*\.(apk)$/i, 'http://mydomain.com?f=">$1</a>'));
});
```

So essentially, remove the code before `download.mydomain.com/files/androidfile.apk`, that is `<a href="http://`   and replace with `<a target="_blank" href="http://mydomain.com?f=http://`. There might be several of this in a page so I need a solution that might match and replace all.

The Regex and replacing doesn't seem to work, what might be a solution to this.

So in summary, I want to be able to do this in JQuery:

```
<html>

<a href="http://download.domain.com/files/androidfile1.apk"><img src="theme/download.gif" border=0 alt="download" height="120px" width="130px"></a><br/>

<a href="http://download.domain.com/files/androidfile2.apk"><img src="theme/download.gif" border=0 alt="download" height="120px" width="130px"></a><br/>

<a href="http://download.domain.com/files/androidfile3.apk"><img src="theme/download.gif" border=0 alt="download" height="120px" width="130px"></a><br/>

<a href="http://download.domain.com/files/androidfile4.apk"><img src="theme/download.gif" border=0 alt="download" height="120px" width="130px"></a><br/>

<a href="http://download.domain.com/files/androidfile5.apk"><img src="theme/download.gif" border=0 alt="download" height="120px" width="130px"></a><br/>

</html>
```

To this:

```
<html>

<a href="http://mydomain2.com?f=http://download.domain.com/files/androidfile1.apk"><img src="theme/download.gif" border=0 alt="download" height="120px" width="130px"></a><br/>

<a href="http://mydomain2.com?f=http://download.domain.com/files/androidfile2.apk"><img src="theme/download.gif" border=0 alt="download" height="120px" width="130px"></a><br/>

<a href="http://mydomain2.com?f=http://download.domain.com/files/androidfile3.apk"><img src="theme/download.gif" border=0 alt="download" height="120px" width="130px"></a><br/>

<a href="http://mydomain2.com?f=http://download.domain.com/files/androidfile4.apk"><img src="theme/download.gif" border=0 alt="download" height="120px" width="130px"></a><br/>

<a href="http://mydomain2.com?f=http://download.domain.com/files/androidfile5.apk"><img src="theme/download.gif" border=0 alt="download" height="120px" width="130px"></a><br/>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is *overkill*, although it won't work, why selecting all the elements on the page? if you want to select `a` elements why not selecting them using `$('a')`? For adding  a string to the `href` attributes, you can use `attr` method.

```
$('a').filter(function() {
    return this.href.indexOf('apk')
}).attr('href', function(i, href) {
    return 'http://mydomain.com?f=' + href
}).attr('target', '_blank');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NCC7u/

Answer (score 1):

The code below should do the trick. Rather than use regex, I used the [ends with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/). This should serve the same purpose, and execute quicker. Instead of rewriting the tag completely, I just modified the attributes using [jQuery.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/). A live example is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/TjYR6/2/).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('a[href$=apk]').each(function()
    {
        var mydomain = "http://mydomain2.com?f=";
        var $this = $(this);

        $this.attr("href", mydomain+$this.attr("href"));
        $this.attr("target", "_blank");
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<a href="http://download.domain.com/files/androidfile1.apk"><img src="theme/download.gif" border=0 alt="download" height="120px" width="130px"></a><br/>
<a href="http://download.domain.com/files/androidfile2.apk"><img src="theme/download.gif" border=0 alt="download" height="120px" width="130px"></a><br/>
<a href="http://download.domain.com/files/androidfile3.apk"><img src="theme/download.gif" border=0 alt="download" height="120px" width="130px"></a><br/>
<a href="http://download.domain.com/files/androidfile4.apk"><img src="theme/download.gif" border=0 alt="download" height="120px" width="130px"></a><br/>
<a href="http://download.domain.com/files/androidfile5.apk"><img src="theme/download.gif" border=0 alt="download" height="120px" width="130px"></a><br/>

</body>
</html>
```

The resulting output is:

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://mydomain2.com?f=http://download.domain.com/files/androidfile1.apk"><img src="theme/download.gif" alt="download" height="120px" border="0" width="130px"></a><br>
<a target="_blank" href="http://mydomain2.com?f=http://download.domain.com/files/androidfile2.apk"><img src="theme/download.gif" alt="download" height="120px" border="0" width="130px"></a><br>
<a target="_blank" href="http://mydomain2.com?f=http://download.domain.com/files/androidfile3.apk"><img src="theme/download.gif" alt="download" height="120px" border="0" width="130px"></a><br>
<a target="_blank" href="http://mydomain2.com?f=http://download.domain.com/files/androidfile4.apk"><img src="theme/download.gif" alt="download" height="120px" border="0" width="130px"></a><br>
<a target="_blank" href="http://mydomain2.com?f=http://download.domain.com/files/androidfile5.apk"><img src="theme/download.gif" alt="download" height="120px" border="0" width="130px"></a><br>
```